# javascript appendChild doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom

i'm having a bug on firefox 3.6 using this function

```
    function GetRefreshedResults(response)
    {   
        var splitted = response.value.split("|");
        var panel = document.getElementById('my-glider');
        var anchors = panel.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++)
        {
          anchors[i].innerHTML=splitted[i];
        }           
    }
```

which ads in DOM anchors like 
      "< a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

I'm now trying to use this instead:

```
     function GetRefreshedResults(response)
    {   
        var splitted = response.value.split("|");
        var panel = document.getElementById('my-glider');
        var anchors = panel.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++)
        {
            anchors[i].empty();
            anchors[i].appendChild(splitted[i]);
          //  anchors[i].innerHTML=splitted[i];
        }           
    }
```

but i get the following error in appendChild :

```
        Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
```

i don't understand why it's not working. can anyone help me ? 
thanks

EDIT:
Example:

splitted[0] contains :

```
   "<div class="var">Visits</div><div class="percent-zero">0%</div><div class="val">0<div class="val-alt">Unique Visits: 0</div></div>"
```

i want to update 8 anchors with new content, contained in splitted[0], splitted[1]...splitted[7]

Comment: What exactly does the value of `response` look like?

Comment: @Dan -- what is in `response` when you tried it? can you make a demo on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Is it really okay to use the index variable "i" which loops over array anchors to select an array element in array "splitted"?

Comment: You have to provide an example for `splitted`. I assume that the HTML it contains is not correct. `innerHTML` should work.

Comment: @FelixKling splitted[0] = "<div 1> <div 2> text </div></div>". I did this thinking that innerHTML will work on all browsers.

Comment: @Dan: Please edit your question and add a properly formated example or better, create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.  `<div 1>` is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`splitted[i]` is the problem. `appendChild` appends a DOM-element to an existing DOM-element, but it looks like you ar trying to append a string value. If you want to use `appendChild`, either create a container element and use `innerHTML` for that to insert the string, or just use `innerHTML`. It is *not* a bug that you can't append a string as DOM-element, I'd say. See also the [MDN-page](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild) on appendChild.

Comment: i didn't say it was a bug. i'm just trying to get rid of that anchor < a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> firefox inserts. I'll try your method right away

Comment: Great Job!!! I created a new div element and used innerHTML on it. Works in firefox! Thanks for the idea

Comment: @Dan, then what's the meaning of: *i'm having a **bug** on firefox 3.6* ;~)

Answer (score 3):

`response.value.split("|");` Indicates to me that you are passing `response` as a string.  appendChild only works with elements.  You can't append a child to a flat string.

Comment: splitted[0] = "<div 1> <div 2> text </div></div>". I did this thinking that innerHTML will work on all browsers.

Comment: @Dan Dinu You're HTML is a bit malformed.  `1` and `2` are not valid attributes.

Comment: i wanted to point out that i have multiple divs in the string.