# Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8 for appendChild call

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript appendChild doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041740/javascript-appendchild-doesnt-work)

The error occurs on the last line of this snippet:

```
 var anchor = "<a id=\"hostname\" href=\"" + destination + "\"> "+ imagename + "</a>";
 var specialdiv = document.getElementById("specialdiv");
 console.log("div: " + specialdiv);
 specialdiv.appendChild(anchor);
```

There's really nothing else going on... I verified that `specialdiv` isn't null or something like that. Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error on that line?

Comment: `appendChild` expects a **DOM element**, not a string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.appendChild

Answer (score 15, accepted):

don't pass a string, but an element

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.innerHTML = imagename;
link.id = "hostname";
link.href = destination;

var specialdiv = document.getElementById("specialdiv");
specialdiv.appendChild(link);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that error because `appendChild` takes DOM elements, not strings.  You need to actually create a DOM element before using `appendChild`.

```
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.id = "hostname";
anchor.href = destination;
anchor.innerHTML = imagename;

var specialdiv = document.getElementById("specialdiv");
specialdiv.appendChild(anchor);
```

Comment: sorry... i was already committed to writing a solution, even though now its darn near a duplicate of yours

Comment: @Kristian: Yep, I'm like a ninja :)

Comment: i can't help but think of die antwoord's ninja song now.. hehe