# not found error: DOM exception 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically creating a select input with options. After the select input is created I assign it to a listitem(newli) like so:

```
   newli.innerHTML =  dynamicDropDown;
```

Then I insert that listitem(newli) into my form like so:

```
  newli.insertBefore('#priceContainer');
```

I get error DOM exception 8
(The code initially inserted my select input even though I was receiving this error, but now that I am calling these functions as part of a for loop; the select input is not being appended and the loop is only executing once) let me know if any more code would help. Thank you. p.s. #pricecontainer is the id of a list item in my form.

Complete Code:

```
        newli = document.createElement('li');
        var dynamicDropDown = '';
        dynamicDropDown="<select>";
            for(j=0; j<choiceArray.length; j=j+1){
                dynamicDropDown+= "<option value='"+choiceArray[j]+"'>"+choiceArray[j]+"</option>";
            }
        dynamicDropDown += "</select>";
        newli.innerHTML =  dynamicDropDown;
        newli.insertBefore('#priceContainer');
```

Comment: `var container=document.getElementById("priceContainer"); newli.insertBefore(container.parentNode,container);`

Comment: can you share the complete code? we need to see how `newli` is created and what is `dynamicDropDown`. Probably you can create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo

Comment: @ArunPJohny I am going to try these answer I got real quick, let me know if anything else helps

Comment: fyi, we were getting this error for latest chrome on mac while using adding element in the dom.

Comment: @HungryCoder well just so you know, I am using Chrome in windows 7 and this answer fixed my problem

Comment: Because createElement makes a DOM node and not a jQuery node!!! It is like making apple juice from oranges. It is not going to happen!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught Error: NOT\_FOUND\_ERR: DOM Exception 8 for appendChild call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640367/uncaught-error-not-found-err-dom-exception-8-for-appendchild-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tough to say exactly as not sure how you create newli element, but if it is a proper element, try:

```
$(newli).html(dynamicDropDown);
$(newli).insertBefore('#priceContainer');
```

Make sure that both newli and priceContainer exist.