# NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8 - javascript

Tags: javascript, exception, dom, insertion

My code:

```
function SubmitCommentAJAX(i)
{
    var thecomment = i.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("styled")[0].innerHTML; 
    var commentBox = document.body.getElementsByClassName("commentsScroll")[0];
    var request = "http://localhost:8080/ituned.com/index?Event=Comment&PostTitle=<%=p.getTitle()%>&PostOwner=<%=p.getUsername_of_Owner()%>&comment="+thecomment;

    xmlhttp.open("POST",request,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {            
            var response=xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("theComment")[0].text;
            **commentBox.insertBefore(response, commentBox.firstChild);**
        }
    };
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="commentsScroll" align="left"> 
    <div></div>             
    </div> 
</div>
```

I get error:  NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8  for the line                                                                              **`commentBox.insertBefore(response, commentBox.firstChild);`**

But commentBox is well defined because when I check with alert(commentBox) it shows me the object.

What is the mistake?

Comment: Did you try using `textContent` instead of `text`?

Comment: no, it is not that i tried it. thanx anyway.

Comment: @Vlenorroia What is `response`? Is it a DOM node? If it is a string, then you are misusing [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore), and your question is a duplicate of [javascript appendChild doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041740/javascript-appendchild-doesnt-work) and [Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8 for appendChild call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640367/uncaught-error-not-found-err-dom-exception-8-for-appendchild-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore) takes a dom node so you'll have to convert the text to a text node

```
var response=xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("theComment")[0].textContent;
commentBox.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(response), commentBox.firstChild);
```

Comment: you were trully right!! but before you hadn't put the createtextnode that is why it did not worked. thanx!

Comment: Not just strings, but also one-element arrays holding a DOM node are invalid arguments for `insertBefore`. Why did I think `splice` doesn't always return an array? :-)